# Enable CORS on custom domain Cloud storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I've set up a Google Cloud Storage bucket with the name of my custom domain (media.xxxxx.tech). This way I can point the nameservers with a CNAME record to `c.storage.googleapis.com` and access the files at `media.xxxxx.tech/[file path]`. I've just followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors) guide on how to enable cors. Even after waiting a couple of hours, nothing changed and there are not `Access allow origin headers` present. This is my cors config:

```
[
  {
    "origin": ["content.*****.tech"],
    "method": ["GET"],
    "responseHeader": [],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

What do I do wrong? How can I solve the problem? Thanks in Advance!